# Is it possible to send a message from one app to another?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, messaging

I have a text messaging app that I want users to be able to text another app of mine on someone else's phone that will show up within the app. Printed on screen. I have one app that will send the message and one app on the receiving device that will display the message. How would I go about doing this?

The receiving app is an opengl app that will display the message in front of a 3d model from the sending app.

If someone could help me out or get me going in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you for your time.

EDIT: This is what I'm doing. I'm making a live wallpaper that women can put on their phone, a seperate "regular" app will allow the husband, fiance, etc to send a message to the lwp on the significant others phone that will display at the top half of the lwp screen.

Comment: your question is not clear enough. maybe you could add a part of code that may help in understanding your question better. What i believe you want to do is make an app which will be installed on two devices in this case. one device will use the app to send the text message to other device using the `SMSManager`. The second device upon receiving the message will display the same on the screen. Am i right?

Comment: Don't forget us men, we also want to receive cutesy messages on our wallpapers too.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) 
{ 
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, 
new Intent(SENT), 0); 

PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, 
new Intent(DELIVERED), 0); 

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault(); 
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI); 
}
```

You can do something like this for sending the sms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

Use [SMSPopup](https://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/) as a working Android project you can use. It has the two parts you need: the sending part and the receiving part, and it's open source. Here it is on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.everythingandroid.smspopup).

The only issue is that the user probably won't want those application messages intermingled with his normal SMS messages.

So you'll want to tag your application text messages with a unique keyword so that the receiving app knows it's a message for itself and no one else. And by tagging, I just mean to insert a unique keyword at the beginning of its subject line.

And your receiving app will have to register a BroadcastReceiver with a priority of 100 so that if it detects a message intended for itself, it can just delete it from the content provider and just do an AbortBroadcast so that the other text messaging apps don't beep for a message that wasn't meant for them in the first place.

In that sense, SMSPopup probably already does 90% of what you need. SMSPopup doesn't automatically delete the sms it receives, nor will it filter them on a particular keyword, but it must silently swallow them so that the normal notification system for sms doesn't get triggered (since SMSPopup provides its own notification popup interface instead).

Answer (score 0):

Hi Steve we have RabbitMQServer to send messages between apps. We should configure the server and need to implement functionlities  to send and receiving messages.
You may get details about RabbitMQ server at http://www.rabbitmq.com/.